# How typed array stores numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, integer, typed-arrays, javascript-engine

If I understood correctly, every number in javascript is 64-bit (i64)?

Does that mean that `new Uint8Array([num])` uses less memory than just `num`?

Comment: The memory for `num` may be less, but you also have to factor in the memory used for the array header.

Comment: But `Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])` should use less memory than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` because the header overhead is amortized.